# Nested iteration over hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, iteration

I have data below I'm trying to update my Models with. Data is a GraphQL.
Company can have multiple `partners: []` (aka. Person) and `partner` can have multiple `addresses[]`.
I want to update `Person.addresses` with `addresses: []` values.

```
mutation updateCompanyPartner {
  updateCompanyPartner(input: {
    uuid: "4c537bd6-cfd5-4141-aefe-9fcaeaffbe51"
    partners: [
      {
        firstName: "Elon"
        lastName: "Musk"
        emailAddress: {
          value: "elon@musk.com"
        }
        addresses: [
        {
          lineOne: "10 New World str."
        },
        {
          lineOne: "10 Old World str."
        }]
      },
      {
        firstName: "Vladimir"
        lastName: "Putin"
        emailAddress: {
          value: "vladimir@putin.com"
        }
        addresses: [
        {
          lineOne: "10 Crimea str."
        },
        {
          lineOne: "10 Tsar str."
        }]
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

First what I do I iterate over each `partners[]` and then check if `value: "elon@musk.com` exist.

If it does I find specific Person to which this email belongs (`person = email_address.party.specific`).

Next I want to iterate over each `person.addresses.map` and update with `addresses[]`.
Below code is an attempt to achieve what I want, however iteration is not performing as expected. Reason why it's not permorming as expected is clear, however I cannot figure out how I should form iteration so it updates values correctly?

```
def create(args)
  partners_data = args[:partners]

  partners_data.map do |params| 
    email_address_data = params[:email_address]
    addresses_data = params[:addresses]

    email_address = EmailAddress.find_by(value: email_address_data[:value])

    if email_address.present?
      person = email_address.party.specific 

      person.addresses.map do |address|
        addresses_data.map do |address_data| 
          address.update!(address_data)      # This part is wrong, shouldn't be iterating this way.
        end
      end
    else
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What arguments are you passing to `create`, and what class is `create` a method of? How is `person.addresses` defined? To find the problem, use [`fetch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) instead of `[]` to throw an error if a key is not found.

Comment: Don't use `map` to iterate, use `each` instead. `map` has a specific purpose. It maps each element in the collection to a new value and produces a new array with results. If you don't use the `map` return value you're better of using `each` since it uses less system resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're iterating over the person's existing addresses and updating each address with all the address's data. The result is that every existing address will be updated to match the last address.

```
# Iterate over each existing address
person.addresses.map do |address|
  # Iterate over each new address
  addresses_data.map do |address_data| 
    # Update the existing address with each new data in turn.
    # Only the last entry in addresses_data will stick.
    address.update!(address_data)
  end
end
```

(Note that `map` is used when you're creating a new array from the result. It will work, but it's a waste of resources and confusing. When you just want to iterate, use `each`.)

Instead, iterate over both `person.addresses` and `addresses_data`. This can be done with [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip).

```
person.addresses.zip(addresses_data).each do |address, data|
  address.update!(data)
end
```

This assumes `person.addresses` and `address_data` have the same length.